# Power of a cycle

Tags: abstract-algebra

> If I have the cycle $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 10 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 9 &
>  12\end{pmatrix}$$ what is $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 10 & 5 & 7 & 2 & 9 &
> 12\end{pmatrix}^5$$

I know that a cycle of prime length raised to any power is again a cycle and I've wondered if there is any algorithmic way of calculating these powers.

Comment: Move from $1$ five steps, you get at $9$; move from $9$ five steps (when hitting the $)$ you go at $1$), so you get at $7$. Continue until getting back at $1$. The cycle is $(1\ 9\ 7\ \dots)$. You get a cycle for any exponent prime to $7$,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to give you an Hint:

If $\sigma$ is your cycle, you have that $\sigma(1)=10$ and 
$$\sigma^2(1)= \sigma (\sigma (1))=\sigma(10)=5$$
You can easely check that $\sigma^5(1)=9$.

Note that $9$ is  the fifth number in your cycle after 1.

Can you generalize this example to obtain you fifth power of $\sigma$?